# Getting value of variable from aspx to codebehind in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm trying to get the time of the initial page load in Silverlight.  To do this I want to set a variable in my aspx page, but then add it to my Application.Resources in the code behind to be used at a different time. I've seen that you can use HiddenFields to do this, but how can I do it to save the value of a DateTime, and access it on the other side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking to pass in a value from your host web page to the Silverlight Application.  You can send the DateTime in as a parameter to the Silverlight application.

Add the param tag to your Silverlight object tag (note the id and the runat="server").

```
<param name="initparams" id="initParams" runat="server" value=""/>
```

Then you can assign its value from the code behind.

```
initParams.Attributes.Add("value", string.Format("PageLoadTime={0}, DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
```

You can then use it in the Silverlight app.xaml.cs Application_Startup method

```
if (e.InitParams.ContainsKey("PageLoadTime"))
        {
            this.YourAppLevelVariable = Convert.ToDateTime(e.InitParams["PageLoadTime"].ToString());
        }
```

**note - this is just a base to get you started.  I would add proper DateTime parsing and error handling, etc.

Comment: I actually currently do this, but we're trying to get "as close as possible" representation of the actual start time.  Therefore, I was going to put a javascript script in the beginning of the .aspx where i do something like var date = new Date(); var millis = date.getMilliseconds().  I was then hoping to save this to the initParams.  I just want to know how to access date and millis from the code behind.

Comment: Nevermind, the code behind gets initialized before the scripts.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can try different lifecycle events to try to get an earlier timeframe in the lifecycle. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx